# Real world, and Mechanize get a different response

Tags: python, html-parsing, mechanize

I'm trying to use the 20 questions database to make a robot play. I'm having a lot of trouble parsing the page to get the questions, and return the answers. When i click on the submit button at http://y.20q.net/gs-en it proceeds to the game, but with mechanize, i get a response that contains the same page. It looks like 20q doesn't want me parsing it, but i disabled robots.txt in mechanize(Which i know is 'wrong'). I'm trying to make a quick and dirty program to get some kids interested in robotics, and using it for demonstration purposes only.

Code:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open('http://y.20q.net/gs-en')
br.select_form(nr=0)

response = br.submit()
print response.read()
```